# Adding transparency to PNGCanvas images

Tags: python, png, alpha-transparency

I've been playing around with [PNGCanvas](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/projects/PNGCanvas), and the one thing I can't figure out is how to add transparency to images. I've been trying to vary the alpha channel values, but it only adjusts the intensity of the color. Am I barking up the wrong tree using this library, or is there hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're barking up the wrong tree. Here's a quote from `PNGCanvas.dump`:

```
# 8-bit image represented as RGB tuples
# simple transparency, alpha is pure white
```

Looking further through its code, when you provide alpha it's just blending it with the background, and the final background is just white.

Comment: any advice? I'm using google app engine and so cannot use PIL. Think there's hope in adding transparency support to this library?

Comment: [The Images Python API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) which is part of App Engine? Says it uses PIL internally.  Never used App Engine myself.

Comment: It's pretty deceiving, they have a few select elements of PIL, but not the whole library.